# Outlook Redemption GetFolderFromPath on public folders

Tags: outlook, outlook-redemption

When I try to access a public folder using Session.GetFolderFromPath I get an error "Error in IMAPITable.FindRow: MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND" at >>:

```
Type COMType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("fkvbmapi.FKRDOSession");
RDOSession session = Activator.CreateInstance(COMType) as RDOSession;
Session.LogonExchangeMailbox(user, server);
>>RDOFolder folder = exchange.Session.GetFolderFromPath(@"\\Public Folders\All Public Folders")
```

Comment: I've found the same problem and was wondering if All Public Folders is always availble assuming there is a public folder database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be necessary to have following code before calling GetFolderFromPath:

```
session.Stores.FindExchangePublicFoldersStore();
```